# sfdisk geometry warning / how to repair

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ext4, fdisk

I have problem with superblock in an ext4 disk :

```
usr@rpb ~ $ sudo fsck -v /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
ext2fs_open2: Numéro magique invalide dans le super-bloc
fsck.ext2 : Superbloc invalide, tentons d'utiliser les blocs de sauvetage...
fsck.ext2: Numéro magique invalide dans le super-bloc lors de la tentative d'ouverture de /dev/sda

Le superbloc n'a pu être lu ou ne contient pas un système de fichiers
ext2 correct. Si le périphérique est valide et qu'il contient réellement
un système de fichiers ext2 (et non pas de type swap, ufs ou autre),
alors le superbloc est corrompu, et vous pourriez tenter d'exécuter
e2fsck avec un autre superbloc :
    e2fsck -b 8193 <périphérique>
```

I tried to repair it ([with this article](https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/)) but do not managed.
I've always the same error.

```
usr@rpb ~ $ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep -i 'superbloc' 
 superbloc Primaire à 0, Descripteurs de groupes à 1-117
 superbloc Secours à 32768, Descripteurs de groupes à 32769-32885
 superbloc Secours à 98304, Descripteurs de groupes à 98305-98421
 superbloc Secours à 163840, Descripteurs de groupes à 163841-163957
 superbloc Secours à 229376, Descripteurs de groupes à 229377-229493
 superbloc Secours à 294912, Descripteurs de groupes à 294913-295029
 superbloc Secours à 819200, Descripteurs de groupes à 819201-819317
 superbloc Secours à 884736, Descripteurs de groupes à 884737-884853
...

usr@rpb ~ $ sudo fsck.ext4 -p -b 98304 /dev/sda
fsck.ext4: Numéro magique invalide dans le super-bloc lors de la tentative d'ouverture de /dev/sda
/dev/sda: 
Le superbloc n'a pu être lu ou ne contient pas un système de fichiers
ext2 correct. Si le périphérique est valide et qu'il contient réellement
un système de fichiers ext2 (et non pas de type swap, ufs ou autre),
alors le superbloc est corrompu, et vous pourriez tenter d'exécuter
e2fsck avec un autre superbloc :
    e2fsck -b 8193 <périphérique>
```

`sfdisk` shows that the geometry of the table seems to be weird.

```
usr@rpb ~ $ sudo sfdisk -luS /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 243201 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Warning: The partition table looks like it was made
  for C/H/S=*/81/62 (instead of 243201/255/63).
For this listing I'll assume that geometry.
Units = sectors of 512 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot    Start       End   #sectors  Id  System
/dev/sda1          2048 3907029166 3907027119  83  Linux
        start: (c,h,s) expected (0,33,3) found (0,32,33)
        end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,80,62) found (513,80,62)
/dev/sda2             0         -          0   0  Empty
/dev/sda3             0         -          0   0  Empty
/dev/sda4             0         -          0   0  Empty
```

Moreover this disk seems to work my current OS (rapsbian) but not with other OS (debian 8).
Anyone have an idea on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You've given fsck the disk descriptor ("sda"), and not that of a
partition/file system (e.g. "sda1"). Hilarity and errors ensue.

Comment: Indeed, this made the job. But I am not able to mount the drive to an other OS (debian). Here is the dmesg stack : 

`[  319.246459] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk`
`[  442.984499] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00`
`[  442.984534] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 08 02 00 00 02 00`
`[  442.984552] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2050`
`[  442.984650] EXT4-fs (sda1): unable to read superblock`